# Magento2.4.5 Session cache limiter cannot be sent after headers have already been sent

Tags: php, magento2

I often see the following issue in my Sentry reporting:

Session cache limiter cannot be sent after headers have already been sent.

This is an error that is thrown when something is outputted before the `session_start()` function is called. But I can't think of anything doing that.

Our set-up is an nginx / php-fpm setup on php8.1 with Varnish caching.

Ayone an idea?

Thx!

```
ErrorException: Warning: session_start(): Session cache limiter cannot be sent after headers have already been sent (output started at /var/www/xxx/magento2/releases/20230503T084213910791/vendor/laminas/laminas-http/src/PhpEnvironment/Response.php:135)
#32 /var/www/xxx/magento2/releases/20230503T084213910791/vendor/magento/framework/Session/SessionManager.php(186): Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManager::start
#31 /var/www/xxx/magento2/releases/20230503T084213910791/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\Session\Generic\Interceptor::___callParent
#30 /var/www/xxx/magento2/releases/20230503T084213910791/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Session\Generic\Interceptor::Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}
#29 /var/www/xxx/magento2/releases/20230503T084213910791/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\Session\Generic\Interceptor::___callPlugins
#28 /Magento/Framework/Session/Generic/Interceptor.php(23): Magento\Framework\Session\Generic\Interceptor::start
#27 /var/www/xxx/magento2/releases/20230503T084213910791/vendor/magento/framework/Session/SessionManager.php(123): Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManager::__construct
#26 /Magento/Framework/Session/Generic/Interceptor.php(14): Magento\Framework\Session\Generic\Interceptor::__construct
#25 /var/www/xxx/magento2/releases/20230503T084213910791/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(121): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory::createObject
#24 /var/www/xxx/magento2/releases/20230503T084213910791/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(108): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled::create
#23 /var/www/xxx/magento2/releases/20230503T084213910791/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(150): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled::get
#22 /var/www/xxx/magento2/releases/20230503T084213910791/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(79): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled::create
#21 /var/www/xxx/magento2/releases/20230503T084213910791/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(150): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled::get
#20 /var/www/xxx/magento2/releases/20230503T084213910791/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(79): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled::create
#19 /var/www/xxx/magento2/releases/20230503T084213910791/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(150): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled::get
#18 /var/www/xxx/magento2/releases/20230503T084213910791/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(79): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled::create
#17 /var/www/xxx/magento2/releases/20230503T084213910791/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(150): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled::get
#16 /var/www/xxx/magento2/releases/20230503T084213910791/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(125): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled::parseArray
#15 /var/www/xxx/magento2/releases/20230503T084213910791/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(86): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled::create
#14 /var/www/xxx/magento2/releases/20230503T084213910791/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager::get
#13 /var/www/xxx/magento2/releases/20230503T084213910791/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(109): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController::__construct
#12 /Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(14): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor::__construct
#11 /var/www/xxx/magento2/releases/20230503T084213910791/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(121): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory::createObject
#10 /var/www/xxx/magento2/releases/20230503T084213910791/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(108): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled::create
#9 /var/www/xxx/magento2/releases/20230503T084213910791/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager::get
#8 /var/www/xxx/magento2/releases/20230503T084213910791/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(115): Magento\Framework\App\Http::launch
#7 /var/www/xxx/magento2/releases/20230503T084213910791/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor::___callParent
#6 /var/www/xxx/magento2/releases/20230503T084213910791/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor::Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}
#5 /var/www/xxx/magento2/releases/20230503T084213910791/app/code/Acme/Sentry/Plugin/GlobalExceptionCatcher.php(33): Acme\Sentry\Plugin\GlobalExceptionCatcher::aroundLaunch
#4 /var/www/xxx/magento2/releases/20230503T084213910791/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor::Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}
#3 /var/www/xxx/magento2/releases/20230503T084213910791/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor::___callPlugins
#2 /Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php(23): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor::launch
#1 /var/www/xxx/magento2/releases/20230503T084213910791/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(264): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::run
#0 /index.php(30): null
```

Only went through the code to find an `echo` or something similar, but didn't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

In our case the redis settings were responsible.

If you have redis configured, try to increase the `max_concurrency` in your `env.php`.

```
            'database' => '2',
            'compression_threshold' => '2048',
            'compression_library' => 'gzip',
            'log_level' => '4',
            'max_concurrency' => '10',    <---- default is 6
            'break_after_frontend' => '5',
            'break_after_adminhtml' => '30',
            'first_lifetime' => '600',
            'bot_first_lifetime' => '60',
```